# Информация по работе с БД

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Хочу научиться работать с БД MySQL, т.е., например, запись данных пользователя при регистрации и извлечение этих данных для проверки верности при авторизации пользователя. Где посоветуете почитать?

Comment: Пользуйтесь яндексом.

Comment: new_russian_man, если уж пользоваться поиском, то не Яндексом, а Google и поисковые системы пока не могут советовать. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Создание регистрации на сайте на PHP + MySQL](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=347).

Answer (score 0):

- [MySQL Reference Manuals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/)
- [Справочное руководство по MySQL 4.0.](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/mysql-man-4.0-ru/)
- [Блоги на Хабре по MySQL](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/mysql/)

И поиск по словам: MySQL, руководство, самоучитель.